# Making writing to a file process more efficient

Tags: python-3.6, coding-efficiency

I am new to programming and i am running this script to clean a large text file (over 12000 lines) and write it to another .txt file. The problem is when a run this with a smaller file (roughly around 500 line) it executes fast, therefore my conclusion was it is taking time due to the size of the file. So if someone can guide me to make this code efficient it will be highly appreciated.

```
input_file = open('bNEG.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
    l_p = LanguageProcessing()
    sentences=[]
    for lines in input_file.readlines():
        tokeniz = l_p.tokeniz(lines)
        cleaned_url = l_p.clean_URL(tokeniz)
        remove_words = l_p.remove_non_englishwords(cleaned_url)
        stopwords_removed = l_p.remove_stopwords(remove_words)
        cleaned_sentence=' '.join(str(s) for s in stopwords_removed)+"\n"
        output_file = open('cNEG.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        sentences.append(cleaned_sentence)
        output_file.writelines(sentences)
    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()
```

**EDIT:** Below is the corrected code as mentioned in the answer with few other alteration to suit my requirements

```
input_file = open('chromehistory_log.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
    output_file = open('dNEG.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    l_p = LanguageProcessing()
    #sentences=[]
    for lines in input_file.readlines():
        #print(lines)
        tokeniz = l_p.tokeniz(lines)
        cleaned_url = l_p.clean_URL(tokeniz)
        remove_words = l_p.remove_non_englishwords(cleaned_url)
        stopwords_removed = l_p.remove_stopwords(remove_words)
        #print(stopwords_removed)
        if stopwords_removed==[]:
            continue
        else:
            cleaned_sentence=' '.join(str(s) for s in stopwords_removed)+"\n"

        #sentences.append(cleaned_sentence)
        output_file.writelines(cleaned_sentence)
    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()
```

Comment: You open the output_file for every line. Try moving "output_file = open('cNEG.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')" above the loop.

Comment: Thank you for replying with a solution @RalphErdt but there was no significant change in the time taken

Comment: Oh.. I oversaw something: You collect all of your Strings in "sentences" and write the whole bunch every loop. -> a) just write in the loop the cleaned_sentence (and do not collect in "sentences") b) collect everything and just write "sentences" after the loop. I prefer a) because its less memory intensive, but its a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

To have the discussion as answer:

Two problems are here:

You open / create the outputfile and write the data in the loop - for every line of the input file. Additional you are collection all data in an array (sentences).

You have two possibilities:

a) Create the file before the loop, and write in the loop just "cleaned_sentence" (and delete the collecting "sentences").

b) Collect everything in "sentences" and write "sentences" at once after the loop.

Disadvantage of a) is: this is a bit slower than b) (as long as the OS di not have to swap memory for b). But the advantage is: This is much less memory consuming and will work no matter how big the file is and how less memory in the computer is installed.

Comment: As you recommended i tried both methods however sticked with method (a). Still it takes a long time..

Comment: Please post corrected code. Additional the times and line count of the different files.

Comment: This code should execute much faster. Do it? How long need it for the 500 lines and how long for the 12K lines? I don't have another ideas.

Comment: for 12k lines it takes more than 10-14 mins

Comment: And for the 0.5K lines files? An how big are the files?

Comment: did not check for 500 lines but lesser the lines it was faster. The 12k file is 2.2MB large.